# How to report telemetry to IOTCentral?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-central

I can't figure out how to report telemetry to IOTCentral.

I created a Device Template, added a Telemetry measurement, Field Name "freeDiskSpace", Maximum Value 999999999999. Got a device associated with the template. Fired up the device code, but looking at the device in Device Explorer of IOTCentral it only says "Missing Data".

First I tried:

```
const upd = {};
upd.freeDiskSpace = info.available;
deviceTwin.properties.reported.update(upd, function (err) {
```

and in the debugger I could see the twin received the data

```
Got device twin
{ reported:
   { update: [Function: update],
     freeDiskSpace: 468716691456,
     '$version': 4 },
```

But nothing in IOTCentral.

Then I noticed how they were sending down desired properties:

```
desired:
 { setCurrent: { value: 0 },
```

so I tried

```
const upd = {};
upd.freeDiskSpace = { value: info.available };
deviceTwin.properties.reported.update(upd, function (err) {
```

but still nothing in IOTCentral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment on another question pointed me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/howto-connect-nodejs which I had somehow never found in all my searching. The key point is that telemetry is reported as an event, not as a reported property. This is counterintuitive to me because I understand an "event" to be a distinct meaningful incident versus "telemetry" being continuous data. But it works. Code snippet from that link:

```
  var data = JSON.stringify({
    temperature: temperature,
    humidity: humidity,
    pressure: pressure,
    fanmode: (temperature > 25) ? "1" : "0",
    overheat: (temperature > 35) ? "ER123" : undefined });
  var message = new Message(data);
  client.sendEvent(message, (err, res) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the *Device Property* to create your device twin reported property on the IoTCentral, see the following screen snippet:

[image]